# Python ggplot format axis number as percent not functioning

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, ggplot2, python-ggplot

Been loving the new ggplot module in Python but I haven't been able to format my y labels as percent instead of decimals. The below code produces the following image. Note that the labels = 'percent' code does not produce the intended format.

```
plot = ggplot(aes(x='Date', y='return', color='Stocks'),data=rx) +\
geom_line() +\
scale_x_date(breaks=date_breaks('1 day'), labels='%b %d %Y') +\
scale_y_continuous(labels= 'percent') +\
ylab('Cumulative Return') + ggtitle('S&P Sector Performance')
```

[image]

Comment: Two thoughts: 1) the percent function is in the scales package; has that been loaded/attached/whatever the nomenclature for the equivalent to `library("scales")` from within Python is? 2) Try without quotes around `percent`; they are not necessary, but they may be allowed (don't recall offhand).

Comment: I knew it came from the 'scales' library but thought I had seen ex with % but it might have been R's ggplot2. I checked yhat's examples and realized they didn't show it so you're probably right in that the 'scales' library hasn't been ported yet. Python requires the the quotation marks. However, it is strange that most of the other scales formatting works including 'comma' and 'millions' etc..

Comment: What happens if you replace `'percent'` with `percent_format()`?

Comment: percent_format() is undefined and produces an error. Anything you pass through to scale_y_continuous(labels= 'percent') that is unrecognized appears to default to standard decimals. That includes misspelled 'commas', '%' etc.

Comment: Oh, I just realized that you are dealing with a port of ggplot2 into python, not a bridge between python and R. I'm afraid that I don't know enough (well, anything) about that to be of any real help. Sorry to send you down dead ends.

Comment: sorry, I'm pretty sure that isn't implemented yet. There is https://github.com/yhat/ggplot/issues/283, which will probably implement this and other scales. Please subscribe there and add your wishes/ usecases. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now available in version 0.5.3 (I just pushed this).

```
>>> from ggplot import *
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({ "x": np.arange(0, 10), "y": np.arange(0, 1, 0.1) })
>>> ggplot(df, aes(x='x', y='y')) +\
... geom_point() +\
... scale_y_continuous(labels='percent')
```

[image: ggplot scale_x_continuous percent]